# import * as speechCommands from "@tensorflow-models/speech-commands" works on React but not NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tensorflow.js

I am trying to rewrite a React application and adapt it to NextJS (since I need to use the backend accessed through /app/api route).

I am getting the error below:

```
./node_modules/@tensorflow-models/speech-commands/dist/speech-commands.esm.js:17:3320
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./components/audio.tsx
./app/audio/page.tsx
```

From the npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/speech-commands) it seems like speech commands is designed to work in the web browser (and it did in the react environment), but it doesn't with nextjs.

I have tried dynamic imports and importing the component when the window is actually defined. This did not work, the can't resolve 'fs' error still was there.

What is going on? And why does it work (in React) despite an import of 'fs'?

Answer (score 0):

I found that someone solved this issue.

I got the same error and it worked for me.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1274

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const config = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      // plugin config, etc
      config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
      return config;
    },
  };
};
```